# .gitignore doesn't see /.idea folder but see .idea

Tags: git, gitignore

.gitignore doesn't see

```
/.idea
```

folder but see

```
.idea
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Because `/` is the root of your filesystem, not the current folder.

Comment: No, it mean the same folder where .gitignore is replaced

Comment: Can you explain more explicitly what you mean? In the second case, it is a plain file or a folder? Can you show the command and output that leads you to conclude what is seen or not?

Comment: What does your gitignore look like?